# How to skip a website to the next if it can't load it (connection error, timeout error, etc..)?

Tags: python, selenium, browser, web-scraping, debian

I have got some websites what I want to webscrape, but sometimes the script is stopping with connection error or timeout error problem.

How can I just skip this problem and continue my script?

Here my code :

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
datatable=[]

browser.get('https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ein/arrivals')
time.sleep(5)
i=0
while i<3:
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "CLICK_EVENT")]').click()
        time.sleep(5) #your try and except cleaned 
        i += 1
    except:
        i=3 #corrected indentation
html = browser.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })

#webscraping part

time.sleep(5) 

os.remove("output.csv") 

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
datatable=[]

browser.get('https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/grz/arrivals')
time.sleep(5)
i=0
while i<3:
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "CLICK_EVENT")]').click()
        time.sleep(5)
        i += 1
    except:
        i=3
html = browser.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })

#webscraping part again

time.sleep(5) 

os.remove("output.csv") 
.
.
.
```

I tried this one:

```
try:
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    datatable=[]

    browser.get('LINK1')
    time.sleep(5)
    i=0
    while i<3:
        try:
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "CLICK_EVENT")]').click()
        time.sleep(5)
        i += 1
        except:
        i=3
except:
    print("Failed to access web-page")
    continue
```

But this is totally wrong, and it isn't working. What can I use the skip this problem?

Comment: can We get the link so that we can test your code on our systems

Comment: Of course, i edited the question with the link!

Comment: where is the button CLICK_EVENT located on that page?

Comment: "load earlier flights"

Comment: In the code you tried, the last line having "continue"  belongs to which loop?

Comment: Yes, i just want to skip the webpages if it cant load it, and go to the next, because if it can't loading the program automatically stopped..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156266/discussion-between-nimish-bansal-and-harley).